# what does mean each digit in system.schedule

Tags: scheduled-apex

I just want to know what each digit means in (String CRON_EXP = '0 0 * * * ?'; ) AND
Can you explain what does meaning for below lines.

```
System.schedule('Hourly', '0 0 * * * ?', new MyHourlySchedule() );  
System.schedule('Start', '0 0 0 10 9 ? 2013' , new MyScheduleStart() );
```

Comment: why don't you read doc https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm

Comment: If is execute System.schedule('Hourly', '0 0 * * * ?', new MyHourlySchedule() ); in anonymous and schedule the Batch apex class every day at 10 PM, will it run every hour for every day, or do we need to do anything to run for every hour for every day

Comment: If you have further question(s) please ask them in a separate question, not in comments.